# Understanding windows setup process

Tags: windows, boot

I want to customize `boot.wim` to start my executable file. However, after adding the command to `startnet.cmd`, it does nothing. I even delete `startnet.cmd` (in `boot.wim`) and Window setup screen still appears like nothing happen.

I want to understand more of the structure and process of how Windows starts and runs its setup environment, similar to how Linux runs `initrd` (which has a lot more in-depth documents) to customize directly. However, I'm unable to find good in-depth resources, as searching Google only yields documents for normal users. Is there anywhere I can find it?

The Windows I'm playing with is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Please add more details about your plan, because working in the boot.wim a bit different than usually in Windows.

Comment: @uDev I want to add a background process that records some information through the entire setup process. When I get into the command prompt (by pressing "Repair this computer"), my program runs fine. But I want it to start automatically.

Comment: What tools did you use for editing boot.wim?

Comment: @uDev I use `dism` to mount, then edit and finally save it.